# Embed Google Calendar in website and use events from calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, calendar

I'm attempting to set up a Google calendar on my website.  Embedding it is pretty easy by just putting the iframe where I want on the page.

```
<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=mycalendar%gmail.com&ctz=America/Edmonton" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I will have a calendar page, but I also want to have a small "upcoming events" section on the home page that displays the event names, dates and times of the next upcoming 3 events.  Is it possible to access the events from the calendar?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google's Calendar API to program some more bespoke Calendar behaviour such as processing particular events in the way you describe. Please see the [Google Calendar API Guide for Javascript](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js).

There is a function within the API example code which comes close to what you're looking to achieve:

```
  /**
   * Print the summary and start datetime/date of the next ten events in
   * the authorized user's calendar. If no events are found an
   * appropriate message is printed.
   */
  function listUpcomingEvents() {
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
      'calendarId': 'primary',
      'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
      'showDeleted': false,
      'singleEvents': true,
      'maxResults': 10,
      'orderBy': 'startTime'
    });

    request.execute(function(resp) {
      var events = resp.items;
      appendPre('Upcoming events:');

      if (events.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
          var event = events[i];
          var when = event.start.dateTime;
          if (!when) {
            when = event.start.date;
          }
          appendPre(event.summary + ' (' + when + ')')
        }
      } else {
        appendPre('No upcoming events found.');
      }

    });
  }
```

Assuming everything else is in order, you should be able to adapt this, using `'maxResults': 3,` instead of `'maxResults': 10,` in order to get the basic events data you're after.

Comment: From what I understand, the question is about how to use the information already in the page, not where to get it from by making another call. If I ask you how to open a box of chocolates I am already holding in my hands you tell me how to get to the nearest candy shop?

Comment: I think that would be the easiest way, however I would suspect that most visitors would run up against cross-domain security barriers, trying to access content within Google's iFrame

Comment: I agree on both. Your answer provides a solution to the problem that generated the question, but it doesn't answer the question. So it's not, technically speaking, a valid answer. Correct?

Comment: Yes, I think so, I had hoped to add a more valuable answer, but the API for Google Calendar has a lot to it. Upon review, the API guide does a very similar thing so I have updated my answer to hopefully be more useful for the specific task at hand

Answer (score 1):

You can access any iframe's contents by using

```
document.getElementById('myFrame').contentWindow.document
```

or, with jQuery

```
$('#myFrame').contents().{...};
```

where your iframe has the id "myFrame".